# Yii 2 - Exception error with message 'Login Required'

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, rbac, yii2-rbac

An Error occurred while handling another error:

> exception 'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'Login
>   Required' in
>   C:\wamp\www\k\kometonline\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\User.php:431

Am getting this error after installing RBAC in backend admin login page (site.com/backend/web/site/login). Whats the main cause of this problem. I don't know what code to post. Please comment below If you need any code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you set behaviors for action

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error while installing RBAC in backend admin login page while following this tutorial:
[RBAC Super Simple with Admin and User](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/771/rbac-super-simple-with-admin-and-user/)

You may try doing the changes you made at the frontend login `SiteController` and see if works. The difference between these two `SiteController`s is that the frontend already uses access rules in its behavior method.

From there you can compare the `SiteController`s at backend and frontend and see what makes it work. In my case I simply added one line

```
'only' => ['logout'],
```

just below

```
'class' => AccessControl::className(),
```

and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

While I know the solution worked for the OP and is a few years old, I wanted to post how I solved this for myself, in the hope of offering an alternate solution.

In my case, I specified the following actions

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'actions' => ['logout', 'index',],
        'allow' => true,
        'roles' => ['@'],
    ],
```

This specified that the index and logout was protected by a password, The

```
*"'roles' => ['@']"*
```

say that only authenticated users can invoke these actions.

Therefore, when my application restarted, it tried to direct to the login action and error presented. I solved this by specifying a rule for non logged in users (a.k.a guests) by specifying the role

```
*"'roles' => ['?']"*
```

My behavior method therefore changed to

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'actions' => ['logout', 'index',],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'actions' => ['login'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```